# Why does my Eclipse keep not responding?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse, and at random times, it will just freeze up and stop responding. Does this happen to anyone else? It usually happens when I click on a line of code, whether it be Java or XML. Any ideas on how to fix it?

System Specs:

[image]

Comment: one question for clarification:  do you mean it freezes and doesn't ever respond again, or is it temporary?  for the latter, one thing i do is add the *Progress View* to the bottom of the perspectives i use most, and leave it open when i'm experiencing these kinds of lags.  the system may be performing some background indexing or something that may be causing it to stop responding.

Comment: I've posted the specs in the original post. It freezes for about 30 seconds and then works suddenly. I've added the Progress view so I'll see if it's doing something in the background.

Comment: Yes, I think there is a tendency for GUI freezes (which do not recover) if trying several things at once if it is responding slowly for whatever reason (not memory in my case). For instance, I tried closing a project and then while it was starting that off, I tried opening a pom in a different project. Boom! I get the feeling the GUI doesn't handle multiple tasks very well. After this, getting it and maven to compile a large number of projects and getting back to the starting point may approach half an hour, unfortunately..

Answer (score 41):

Open your `workspace\.metadata\.log` file. That will tell you usually what is going wrong.

Comment: @KFP Can you try pointing eclipse to a new workspace and work using it for a while?

Comment: @AjayGeorge, How can we find out where is the `workspace` folder if Eclipse wouldn't even respond?

Comment: Add `-showlocation` argument to your eclipse startup . It will show the workspace on the title bar

Comment: @AjayGeorge, Yuur solution doesn't work btw. The log doesn't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @AjayGeorge - Your suggestion of opening in a new workspace just worked for me. I did this: 1. Shut down Eclipse, which was (Not Responding). 2. Reopened using another workspace. 3. Shut it down again. 4. Reopened in the original workspace.

Answer (score 30):

Try this, it worked for me!

If you happen to have Eclipse not responding anymore sometimes, the reason could be that you sit on a 64bit machine where eclipse needs more memory. Be sure to have (at least) the following configurations in your eclipse.ini (I even use bigger values for the PermSizes):

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:PermSize=64m
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Comment: Worked nicely. Thank you. Btw, I didn't have permisize or maxpermsize intially. What are these for?

Comment: How about similar settings for Java 8? (These do not exist anymore in Java 8.)

Comment: afaik they should be -ms and -mx now, in fact these have existed previously, the X-ones have been deprecated for a while

Comment: wow I can't believe it was this simple. You'd think a 64 bit .zip/installer would have this setting by default

Comment: Since, Java 8 PermGen support has been disabled, instead MetaSpace is used. Instead of PermSize, use, ```-XX:MetaspaceSize=128M``` and ```-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M```

Comment: Thanks for your advice but this does not help - as soon as I click on any source code in eclipse it crashes. This only happened since last week, was working fine for a year or so on a very large project before that.

Answer (score 15):

I just restarted the [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) (Android Debug Bridge) this way:

1. adb kill-server
2. adb start-server

and it works again!

Comment: Though this wouldn't work, it was the right idea for me. `$ killall adb` did the trick on Ubuntu

Comment: Eclipse engineers need to get their act together and stop hanging the UI due to long running processes. Whatever happened to responsive UI design?

Comment: What if you're not using android?

Comment: @user1794106, adb is an android tool so this cannot be the solution, I would try for the other solutions.

Answer (score 10):

Last night at 2am I closed my Eclipse (Juno) just fine. This morning I open it up and I get nothing but "Not Responding" on my 64bit Windows 7 machine.

I looked in `[workspace]\.metadata\.log` and it showed an error with `Invalid property category path: ValidationPropertiesPage`

**I cuss it out pretty good and then show it who's the boss :**

1. delete `[workspace]\.metadata` folder
2. delete `[workspace]\[project]\.settings`
3. Open up Eclipse to the same workspace as before, re-import your
   project.

Which brings me to another topic... Eclipse -> import -> Android -> Existing Android code into workspace... seems to be broken once again. But that's a different topic.

Comment: +1 I think over time my projects were upgraded to different versions of Eclipse which shows in my logs. I like the fresh start approach.

Answer (score 2):

Very likely your filesystem is out of sync with your Eclipse... Resource is out of sync with the file system.   Using SVN?  If you "Refresh" all of your projects in explorer, speed returns to normal.

Comment: As an addition, my problem was while trying to sync with repository Eclipse would always hang. Project -> Clean fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar symptoms recently. Turned out it was caused by the Subversion server being unavailable - once that was restarted I was able to right-click. My environment was Eclipse Luna with Subclipse.

So worth checking that any connected source control systems are operational. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

for me, it was because of all the outgoing files, i.e workspace is not in sync with SVN, due to the 'target' folders (maven project, or when building web project), add them to svn:ignore.

Answer (score 1):

I kept running into this problem every time I tried opening eclipse.  I resolved it by unplugging my android device's USB from my laptop, and eclipse worked again.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a project you earlier imported externally (outside of **Workspace**), that may cause this problem. If you can access Eclipse try to remove it. If you are getting the '**No responding at startup**', then go delete the file at source.

This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like you. But I am Windows 8.1 64 bit user. At first I use eclipse Kepler on my 8.1. The eclipse often become not responding when I worked on. After that, I decide to back to eclipse Juno and it works fine now.

Answer (score -5):

This may help

In your eclipse,

1) Go to Help

2) Click Eclipse marketplace

3) search - optimizer

install "optimizer for eclipse"

[image]

Comment: Run away.  That optimzer requires an email and user name, and it broke my Eclipse config.  Now Kepler won't even start because the memory settings prevent the creation of the JVM.  I had it all working... then I "fixed" it with this non-optimizer.  Now I have to "unoptimize" the configuration to get it working again.  Flame suit on.