# Issues while working with Worklight 6.1.0.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Environment:

Worklight 6.1.0.2,
Dojo 1.9.4

We have developed a hybrid app using worklight and dojo. We are facing following issues while working with worklight -

1. After starting the worklight server, we are accessing the simulator in chrome browser. Most of the time, worklight is unable to load the app in simulator and browser show "Page is not responsive" error message. You have to keep your finger cross, to see it work. If the simulator started successfully, then you should not close the simulator or stop the worklight server. If you do that, then you have to do all the circus to make it work - Restart worklight server, restart eclipse, restart machine.
2. "Build All Environments" is not updating the recent changes in the simulator. You have to use "Run on worklight development server" option to update the recent changes in the simulator.
3. Slow building speed. It takes 5-10 mins to build the environment.
4. Occasional eclipse freezing when working with html file.

These issues are affecting the productivity of the team and we are not able to make quick progress on the project.

Any help on these issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does it also happen when running the app in the Android Emulator or iOS Simulator, or only when previewing in a browser? Does it happen in all browsers or only in Chrome? Can this be observed in any app or only in your app? If only in your app, you need to provide a sample of it that the "circus" can be observed, with *detailed reproduction steps*. Consider opening a PMR for this specific issue.
2. That makes sense. Build all environments *builds* the web resources - it does not *deploy* them to the server. When previewing the application, the resources are *served* by the server. As you say, Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server will solve this.
3. Dojo adds a lot to an application. This cannot be helped.
4. You can [try adding additional memory](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F) to Eclipse. You can possibly also find the issue [in this log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638964/why-does-my-eclipse-keep-not-responding).

Comment: Thanks @Idan for the reply. Reply to point 1 - We are seeing the issue when previewing in the browser. We don't use Android Emulator, as browser allows us to debug the javascript files. I have seen these issue on  FireFox as well. But we normally use Chrome browser as it allows to start browser with same origin policy. We just have single app, so haven't tested with other apps.

Comment: Actually you can also debug JavaScript in a device/emulator. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396372/ibm-worklight-how-do-i-enable-webview-debugging-in-android - it works very well.

Comment: The worklight console shows following error, if you close the browser after closing "Page is not responsive" error message dialog -

[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: 
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport.constructErrorReport(WebAppErrorReport.java:153)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport.constructErrorReport(WebAppErrorReport.java:194)